# XSD Custom NameSpace creating issue in POM.XML while execution in SpringBoot

Tags: java, xml, maven, spring-boot, xsd

**strong text**I have added one custom namespace into other xsd file as shown below:

```
<s:import namespace="http://COM.Services" schemaLocation="USER.xsd" />
```

Without above namespace generating the java classes without any issues.

If we added above line into existing xsd showing error in pom.xml  tag and both xsd target namespaces are different .

POM.XML as below:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.6</version>
<executions>
    **<execution>** //here showing error
         <id>xjc</id>
             <goals>
                 <goal>xjc</goal>
             </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
</configuration>
```

Please suggest on this.

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: Why are you using such an older version of jaxb2-maven-plugin ? http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.3.1/

Comment: @khmarbaise, After updating the latest version error is removed but java classes are not generated.Please help on this.